# Beef stew disaster

Tags: beef

I made some beef stew in my crock pot. I forgot to plug it in. It's been sitting for going on 5 hours. Is it dog food now or would the broth have saved it so I can still cook and eat it? Edit: I threw it out. Didn't want to chance it.